# Check If date is over a 2 weeks old

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I’m trying to create a `if` statement that checks a date against the current date and throw a `error` if its less that 2 weeks old.

My current code

```
const moment = require('moment')
const today = moment().format()

const createdDate = '2020-07-30'
if (createdDate <= today ) {
console.log('Good')
} else {
console.log('Bad')
};
console.log(today)
```

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What is 'moment' and why is it required?  Why not just use native Date() features?

Comment: moment is a common date library for working with JS dates. Native date features have come along way but the moment API is a little easier to work with for many devs. Obviously has it's downsides (3rd party, could increase bundle time if used on client, etc.) but it's widely used and well supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `add` feature of `Moment` as well.

```js
const today = moment();
const createdDate = moment("2020-07-30")

if (createdDate.add(2, 'weeks').isSameOrAfter(today)) {
   console.log('good to go!')
} else {
   console.log('bad')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZsWP0vT+akWmvEMkNYgZrPHKU9Ke8nYBPC3dqONp1mY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use moments `subtract` feature along with `isSameOrAfter`.
There is another option where you add two weeks to the createdDate and compare that today as well. Whichever makes more sense for you.

```
const today = moment();
const createdDate = moment("2020-08-30")

if (today.subtract(2, 'weeks').isSameOrAfter(createdDate)) {
   console.log('good')
} else {
   console.log('bad')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this **two** ways and you can choose what suit you better. Both `solution` below will perfectly for your scenario.

You can simply use moment [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) function by getting the difference of `days` in numbers and if the `difference` is more then or equal to `14` days then its `good` else it will be `bad`.

> Using diff function

**Live Demo:**

```js
var today = moment().startOf('day')
var createdDate = moment("2020-07-30", "YYYY-MM-DD").startOf('day')
var diff = today.diff(createdDate, 'days')

if (diff >= 14) {
  console.log('Good')
} else {
  console.log('Bad')
};
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.js"></script>
```

> Using add function and clone function get the results

You can use add function along with `clone` and using `startOf` day function to make sure we always get the date from day start not when when performed the operation to check for comparison.

**Live Demo:**

```js
let today = moment().startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD') //today
let createdDate = moment('2020-07-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD').clone().add(14, 'days').startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD') //created date minus two weeks
if (createdDate <= today) {
  console.log('Good')
} else {
  console.log('Bad')
};
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.js"></script>
```